# Rails and html form (materialize in this case)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, material-design, materialize

I am creating a table for my Product model. As headers, I will have the attribute names, and in the body the rows will represent a record for which I want to add values and then save .At the moment, I'm sketching this up as a HTML/CSS ( with Materialize)

```
    <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Document</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>12/12/2017</td>
        <div>
        <td>
          <select class = "browser-default">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
          <option value ="1">Option 1</option>
          <option value ="2">Option 2</option>
          </select>
        </td>
          <td class ="input-field col s6" >
          <input id="last_name" type="text" class="validate">

</table>
```

If I want to keep the provided option, input, checkboxes from materialize, how can I save my record ( I want to still use  input-field for e.g. and the value that I put there to be saved) 
How can I adapt this to Rails form?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Answer (score 0):

You'll want something like this in a `html.erb` file:

```
    ...
    <tbody>
      <% @products.each do |product| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= product.id %></td>
          <td><%= product.your_date_column %></td>
          <%= form_for product do |f| %>
            <td>

              <%= f.select :browser_default, [["Option 1", 1], ["Option 2, 2"]], include_blank: "Choose your option" %>
            </td>
            <td class ="input-field col s6" >
              <%= f.input :last_name %>
            </td>
          <% end %>
          ...
```

Couple of things to note:

- You'll need to set `@products` in the relevant controller action.
- This then iterates through these, creating a row for each product.
- You'll need a submit button for this form, or to establish how to submit using AJAX. The former is simpler and would just need `<%= f.submit %>` adding to the row.

Hope that helps - let me know how you get on or if you have any questions :)

Comment: Did this help at all @begginnersquestions?